# How do I use hive in a jsp or servlets? I want to create a website that uses hive queries

Tags: jsp, hadoop, servlets, hive

My code is working great without the use of JSP or servlet, please specify any special imports or connection or modifications required?

Comment: The question is too vague and contain less details on the requisites.

Answer (score 0):

You can query hive through your java code using hive jdbc connection.

Hive query execution takes long duration. If you want to import data from hadoop, I would recommend you to use impala or some other tool which is best suited for this purpose. You can use jdbc connection to impala service and retrieve results way faster than hive.

Again, these tools are only for querying.